# Dump Complete for loop outputs to text file in Python

Tags: python

I am running for loop to read file (txt) and slice the information inside the file.

after slicing i was trying to dump the whole result into Text file as of below code:

```
import subprocess
jabber = open('C:/Users/Ahmed Mustafa/Desktop/Network Latency Measuring Tool/output.txt','r')
for line in jabber:
    if 'statistics' in line.lower():
        iploc = line.find("for ") +4
        iplocend = line.find(":",iploc)
        print(line[iploc:iplocend])
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        sentloc = line.find("Sent")
        sentlocend = line.find(",",sentloc)
        print(line[sentloc:sentlocend])
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        rxloc = line.find("Received")
        rxlocend = line.find(",",rxloc)
        print(line[rxloc:rxlocend])
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        losloc = line.find("Lost")
        loslocend = line.find(" (",losloc)
        print(line[losloc:loslocend])
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        lossloc = line.find("(")+1
        losslocend = line.find(" loss",lossloc)
        print(line[lossloc:losslocend] + " Loss")
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        maxloc = line.find("Maximum")
        maxlocend = line.find(",",maxloc)
        print(line[maxloc:maxlocend])
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        minloc = line.find("Minimum")
        minlocend = line.find(",",minloc)
        print(line[minloc:minlocend])
        result = line[minloc:minlocend]
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        avgloc = line.find("Average")
        avglocend = line.find(",",avgloc)
        print(line[avgloc:avglocend])
        result = line[avgloc:avglocend]
        print('-'*60)
jabber.close()

with open("outputp.txt", "w") as outputp:
    outputp.writelines(str(result))
```

This code output is as the following:

```
8.8.8.8
Sent = 4
Received = 4
Lost = 0
0% Loss
Maximum = 279ms
Minimum = 158ms
Average = 195ms
------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1
Sent = 4
Received = 4
Lost = 0
0% Loss
Maximum = 0ms
Minimum = 0ms
Average = 0ms
------------------------------------------------------------
```

But, when i checked the output file named "outputp.txt" i found only the last result appear as the below:

```
Average = 0ms
```

Comment: Lots of issues with that code but I'll address the question -- every time you do `result = x` you overwrite the variable, so it's probably only appending the last line because you're overwriting `result` to only include this

Comment: it seems this is the situation, is there any recommendations to accumulate the output results in one file?

Comment: You could open 2 files at once, and write to the 2nd file inside your loop instead of doing `result = x` or else otherwise you can just do `result += x` so that it appends the string instead of overwriting it

Comment: ``result += x`` worked for me but it gave unorganized results as the following:       
 ``Average = 0msMinimum = 158msAverage = 195msMinimum = 0msAverage = 0msMinimum = 158msAverage = 195msMinimum = 0msAverage = 0ms``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by including `result += x` at each if nest also by adding some formatting like `'\n'`
Also, added `result = ''` before the for loop to clear the variable and prevent data from accumulating and here is the final code:

```
import subprocess
jabber = open('C:/Users/Ahmed Mustafa/Desktop/Network Latency Measuring 
Tool/output.txt','r')
result = ""
for line in jabber:
    if 'statistics' in line.lower():
        iploc = line.find("for ") +4
        iplocend = line.find(":",iploc)
        print(line[iploc:iplocend])
        result += (line[iploc:iplocend] + '\n')
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        sentloc = line.find("Sent")
        sentlocend = line.find(",",sentloc)
        print(line[sentloc:sentlocend])
        result += (line[sentloc:sentlocend] + '\n')
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        rxloc = line.find("Received")
        rxlocend = line.find(",",rxloc)
        print(line[rxloc:rxlocend])
        result += (line[rxloc:rxlocend] + '\n')
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        losloc = line.find("Lost")
        loslocend = line.find(" (",losloc)
        print(line[losloc:loslocend])
        result += (line[losloc:loslocend] + '\n')
    if 'packet' in line.lower():
        lossloc = line.find("(")+1
        losslocend = line.find(" loss",lossloc)
        print(line[lossloc:losslocend] + " Loss")
        result += (line[lossloc:losslocend] + " Loss"  + '\n')
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        maxloc = line.find("Maximum")
        maxlocend = line.find(",",maxloc)
        print(line[maxloc:maxlocend])
        result += (line[maxloc:maxlocend] + '\n')
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        minloc = line.find("Minimum")
        minlocend = line.find(",",minloc)
        print(line[minloc:minlocend])
        result += (line[minloc:minlocend] + '\n')
    if 'minimum' in line.lower():
        avgloc = line.find("Average")
        avglocend = line.find(",",avgloc)
        print(line[avgloc:avglocend])
        result += (line[avgloc:avglocend] + '\n')
        print('-'*60)
jabber.close()

with open("outputp.txt", "w") as outputp:
    outputp.writelines(str(result))
```